# アコーディオンメニューで入力しているとき項目のみ開いた状態にする

Tags: javascript, html, css

アコーディオンメニューでメニューを開閉の設定をしていますが、入力している項目だけ開いた状態にし、
他のメニューは閉じた状態にするにはどうすればいいでしょうか。

http://www.dataplan.jp/blog/css/3127
ここのサイトを参考にして作りたいのですが、

```
<div id="accordion" class="accordionbox">
    <dl class="accordionlist">
        <dt class="clearfix">
            <div class="title">
                <p>＋、－切り替え</p>
            </div>
            <p class="accordion_icon"><span></span><span></span></p>
        </dt>
        <dd>＋、－切り替え</dd>
        <dt class="clearfix">
            <div class="title">
                <p>＋、－切り替え</p>
            </div>
            <p class="accordion_icon"><span></span><span></span></p>
        </dt>
        <dd>＋、－切り替え</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $(".accordionbox dt").on("click", function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle();   
        // activeが存在する場合
        if ($(this).children(".accordion_icon").hasClass('active')) {           
            // activeを削除
            $(this).children(".accordion_icon").removeClass('active');              
        }
        else {
            // activeを追加
            $(this).children(".accordion_icon").addClass('active');         
        }           
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.accordionbox{
    width: 50%;
    background:#FBDBC4;
    margin: 10px auto 40px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.accordionlist dt{
    display:block;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px 0 10px 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
}
.accordionlist dt:first-child{
    border-top: none !important;
}
.accordionlist dt .title{
    padding-left: 10px;
    float: left;
}
.accordionlist dd{
    display:none;
    background: #fff;
    padding:0 0 20px 15px;
}
.accordion_icon,
.accordion_icon span {
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all .4s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.accordion_icon {
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.accordion_icon span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 6px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #F88789;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
}
.accordion_icon span:nth-of-type(1) {
    top: 5px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.accordion_icon span:nth-of-type(2) {
    top: 5px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
/*＋、－切り替え*/
.accordion_icon.active span:nth-of-type(1) {
    display:none;
}
.accordion_icon.active span:nth-of-type(2) {
    top: 5px;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<dd>＋、－切り替え</dd>
```

ddで囲んだ部分に、
ここの部分にcheckboxにチェック済みや
inputの入力画面で入力済みの場合、
だと開いている状態にするにはどうすればよいのでしょうか。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　回答へのコメントが回答として投稿されていましたが、こちらでコメントに変換しておきました。回答欄とコメント欄を使い分けて頂ければと思います。よろしくお願いいたします <(\_ \_)>

Answer (score 1):

メニュー項目に対し開いた状態にしたい条件でフィルタをかけて、クリック時の表示制御と同様のことをする流れになると思います。

以下は実装例です。

```js
$(function() {
  // 初期開閉状態設定
  $(".accordionbox dt")
    .filter((i, e) => isActive($(e).next()))
    .each((i, e) => toggle($(e)));

  $(".accordionbox dt").on("click", function() {
    toggle($(this));
  });
});

function toggle($dt) {
  $dt.next().slideToggle();
  // activeが存在する場合
  if ($dt.children(".accordion_icon").hasClass('active')) {
    // activeを削除
    $dt.children(".accordion_icon").removeClass('active');
  } else {
    // activeを追加
    $dt.children(".accordion_icon").addClass('active');
  }
}

// 初期開閉状態の判定
function isActive($dd) {
  // 特定のラジオボタンをチェックしているか
  if ($dd.find('input[type="radio"].close:checked').length)
    return false;
  // チェックボックスをチェックしているか
  if ($dd.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length)
    return true;
  // テキストボックスに入力があるか
  if ($dd.find('input[type="text"]').filter((i, e) => $(e).val()).length)
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

```css
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.accordionbox {
  width: 50%;
  background: #FBDBC4;
  margin: 10px auto 40px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.accordionlist dt {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px 0 10px 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
}

.accordionlist dt:first-child {
  border-top: none !important;
}

.accordionlist dt .title {
  padding-left: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.accordionlist dd {
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 0 20px 15px;
}

.accordion_icon,
.accordion_icon span {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all .4s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accordion_icon {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.accordion_icon span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #F88789;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
}

.accordion_icon span:nth-of-type(1) {
  top: 5px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.accordion_icon span:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 5px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
}


/*＋、－切り替え*/

.accordion_icon.active span:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: none;
}

.accordion_icon.active span:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 5px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion" class="accordionbox">
  <dl class="accordionlist">
    <dt class="clearfix">
      <div class="title">
        <p>チェック済</p>
      </div>
      <p class="accordion_icon"><span></span><span></span></p>
    </dt>
    <dd><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" /></dd>
    <dt class="clearfix">
      <div class="title">
        <p>未チェック</p>
      </div>
      <p class="accordion_icon"><span></span><span></span></p>
    </dt>
    <dd><input type="checkbox" /></dd>
    <dt class="clearfix">
      <div class="title">
        <p>入力済</p>
      </div>
      <p class="accordion_icon"><span></span><span></span></p>
    </dt>
    <dd><input type="text" value="hoge" /></dd>
    <dt class="clearfix">
      <div class="title">
        <p>未入力</p>
      </div>
      <p class="accordion_icon"><span></span><span></span></p>
    </dt>
    <dd><input type="text" /></dd>
    <dt class="clearfix">
      <div class="title">
        <p>特定のラジオボタンチェック済</p>
      </div>
      <p class="accordion_icon"><span></span><span></span></p>
    </dt>
    <dd><input type="radio" class="close" checked="checked" /><input type="text" value="hoge" /></dd>
    <dt class="clearfix">
      <div class="title">
        <p>特定のラジオボタン未チェック</p>
      </div>
      <p class="accordion_icon"><span></span><span></span></p>
    </dt>
    <dd><input type="radio" class="close" /><input type="text" value="hoge" /></dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。 スニペットを実行してうまくいっているので、
bootstrapの開閉するコードは無くした方がいいでしようか。

Comment: @user25636 無くす検討対象のコードはどの部分でしょうか。jQuery の `slideToggle()` のことであれば、開閉を行うために必要になります。スニペットでの動作を作るうえでは必要十分だと思いますが、期待する動作と違うためなんらかの修正をしたいということでしょうか。

Comment: bootstrapで開閉していたので、それを削除しました。うまくいきましたが、何もデータが入っていない時は開いた状態になります。データがあるときは閉じた状態です。あと、特定のラジオボタンをチェックしているときに閉じるにはどうすればいいでしょうか。。

Comment: @user25636 さんのお手元の環境下での話でしょうか。すみませんが詳細がわからないもので、ある程度問題を切り出した上で、現在お困りの事象にスポットをあてて再質問などの形で対応していただけますか。特定のラジオボタンをチェックしているときに閉じる動きについては回答を更新しました。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。わからないところは別途質問いたします。